# JavaFX WebView ScrollEvent listener zooms in and scrolls. Only want it to zoom in

Tags: java, javafx, webview

I've been looking around to see if anyone has had this issue, but most of the issues seem unrelated. I have a JavaFX WebView inside of a scrollpane. I'm attempting to make it so when you hold ctrl + scrollwheel, it will zoom in and out accordingly.

The code does zoom in and out, but incorrectly. When I hold ctrl + scroll wheel, it both scrolls and zooms in or out.

Here is the relevant part of my code:

```
// Allow for dynamic zooming based on scrollwheel
  webview.addEventHandler(ScrollEvent.SCROLL, (ScrollEvent e) -> {
     System.out.println("Zoom in or out based on scroll bar");
     double deltaY = e.getDeltaY();
     System.out.println(deltaY + "    " + e.isControlDown());
     if(e.isControlDown() && deltaY > 0) {
        webview.setZoom(webview.getZoom() * 1.1);
     } else if(e.isControlDown() && deltaY < 0) {
        webview.setZoom(webview.getZoom() / 1.1);
     }
  });
```

I left the printout statements in to help with possible troubleshooting. Thank you ahead of time.

**EDIT**

I should probably include that I placed the WebView in the ScrollPane like so:

```
scrollpane.setContent(webview);
```

Comment: What happens if you add your `EventHandler` as a filter (via `addEventFilter`) and consume the `ScrollEvent` if the `ctrl` key is down?

Comment: I can't scroll up or down at all after that change.

Comment: Actually, @Slaw, you were right. I placed consume at the end of the listener, instead of inside the ifs. I'll post the answer unless you want to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Slaw commented in my question, all I had to do was consume the event inside of my if statements and change the event processor from handler to a filter as shown below:

```
webview.addEventFilter(ScrollEvent.SCROLL, (ScrollEvent e) -> {
     double deltaY = e.getDeltaY();
     if(e.isControlDown() && deltaY > 0) {
        webview.setZoom(webview.getZoom() * 1.1);
        e.consume();
     } else if(e.isControlDown() && deltaY < 0) {
        webview.setZoom(webview.getZoom() / 1.1);
        e.consume();
     }
  });
```

Comment: Excellent, works perfectly!
Does this also work cross-platform (Mac OS) using a standard mac trackpad?

Comment: Never mind - found it: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/ZoomEvent.html
(i.e.: webview.addEventFilter(ZoomEvent.ZOOM, (ZoomEvent e)... )